# After generating log file how to write it into CSV

Tags: python

```
import random
import datetime

levels = ['CRITICAL','INFO','ERROR','WARNING','DEBUG']
module = ['web.py','setup.py','module.py','admin.py','views.py']
messages = ['email failed ','Info message','Warning message','Critical message']
dates = ['2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122','2016-04-03 1:34:24.168122','2016-04-11 12:34:24.278002','2016-04-17 08:04:24.978192','2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132']

def get_random_log_level():
    x = levels[random.randint(0,len(levels)-1)]
    return x

def get_random_message():
    y = messages[random.randint(0,len(messages)-1)]
    return y

def get_random_module():
    z = module[random.randint(0,len(module))-1]
    return z

def generate_log_line():
    level = get_random_log_level()
    date =  dates[random.randint(0,len(dates))-1]
    dt = str(date)
    modulestr = get_random_module()
    msg = get_random_message()
    s = "{0} {1} {2} {3} \n".format(dt,level,modulestr,msg)
    return s

def create_log_file(filename=None):
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        for x in range(5000):
            f.write(generate_log_line())
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_log_file('Test.txt')
```

Above code generates log file using following format:-

> ```
> 2016-04-03 1:34:24.168122 DEBUG web.py email failed  
> 2016-04-17 08:04:24.978192 WARNING module.py Critical message   
> 2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122 DEBUG web.py email failed  
> 2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132 DEBUG setup.py Info message 
> 2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132 ERROR module.py email failed  
> 2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132 CRITICAL views.py email failed <br>
> ```

Now I want to read log file and parse some data like *dt*,level,*msg* to *csv* file
bellow is my code but gives error:- too many values to unpack please help?

```
import csv
import itertools
import generate_logs

def read_log_file_to_csv(filename=None):
    with open('logs.csv','w') as csv:
        csv.write("Date, Levels, Message")
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            dt,level,msg = parse_log_file(line)
            csv.write("{0} {1} {2}".format(dt,level,msg))

def parse_log_file(line):  
    dt,level,msg = line.split("\t")
    return dt,level,msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_log_file_to_csv('Test.txt')
```

Comment: The file is not separated by a tab `\t` but by spaces, at least that's what you write in your first code. You also write *four* values and try to read only *three*. That does not match.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing 4 elements on a log line:

```
s = "{0} {1} {2} {3} \n".format(dt,level,modulestr,msg)
```

You are splitting the log line and want to put it in 3 variables:

```
dt,level,msg = line.split("\t")
```

That is not going to work: it expects 3 variables (because that is what you give it to write to) and it gets 4. You can do

```
dt,level,modulestr,msg = line.split("\t")
```

and just don't use the variable that you don't need.

EDIT:

If you want to split your line on tabs, you will have to make sure it HAS some tabs. So change

```
s = "{0} {1} {2} {3} \n".format(dt,level,modulestr,msg)
```

to

```
s = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(dt,level,modulestr,msg)
```

Comment: Note that the file is using a space ` ` as the separator, not the tab `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your parsing functions to fit your needs. There are several things to mention. The first one is `split`. Which splits your string in to many parts (as the error message says). The second one is the indentation of the function `read_log_file_to_csv`, which opens a file (with statement) and closes it. Here is a complete example with log generation and parsing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

levels = ['CRITICAL','INFO','ERROR','WARNING','DEBUG']
module = ['web.py','setup.py','module.py','admin.py','views.py']
messages = ['email failed ','Info message','Warning message','Critical message']
dates = ['2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122','2016-04-03 1:34:24.168122','2016-04-11 12:34:24.278002','2016-04-17 08:04:24.978192','2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132']


def get_random_log_level():
    x = levels[random.randint(0, len(levels)-1)]
    return x


def get_random_message():
    y = messages[random.randint(0, len(messages)-1)]
    return y


def get_random_module():
    z = module[random.randint(0, len(module))-1]
    return z


def generate_log_line():
    level = get_random_log_level()
    date = dates[random.randint(0, len(dates))-1]
    dt = str(date)
    modulestr = get_random_module()
    msg = get_random_message()
    s = "{0} {1} {2} {3} \n".format(dt, level, modulestr, msg)
    return s


def create_log_file(filename=None):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for x in range(5000):
            f.write(generate_log_line())
    return


def read_log_file_to_csv(filename=None):
    with open('logs.csv', 'w') as csv:
        csv.write("Date, Levels, Message\n")
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                dt, level, msg = parse_log_file(line)
                csv.write("{0}, {1}, {2}".format(dt, level, msg))


def parse_log_file(line):
    line = line.split(" ")
    dt = " ".join(line[:2])
    level = line[2:3]
    msg = " ".join(line[3:])
    return dt, level, msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_log_file('Test.txt')
    read_log_file_to_csv('Test.txt')
```

Outout:

```
Date, Levels, Message
2016-04-11 12:34:24.278002, ['WARNING'], setup.py Info message 
2016-04-11 12:34:24.278002, ['ERROR'], module.py Warning message 
2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122, ['ERROR'], views.py email failed  
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132, ['ERROR'], web.py Critical message 
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132, ['DEBUG'], module.py Critical message 
2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122, ['WARNING'], views.py email failed  
2016-04-01 11:34:24.278122, ['DEBUG'], views.py email failed  
2016-04-11 12:34:24.278002, ['ERROR'], module.py Info message 
2016-04-23 04:44:43.472132, ['INFO'], views.py email failed 
...
```

You should consider using the [csv moudle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: I have change code as per your suggestion but getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: I added a complete example with log generation and parsing

Comment: Thanks @salomonderossi. I have run your code but in csv there is no data in level and Message column. date also not shows in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed that way because only the last field can contain spaces, but the usage would be to use a separator cannot be contained in any field.

By using the second parameter of split you can change the `parse_log_file` function to:

```
def parse_log_file(line):  
    dt,level,msg = line.split(" ", 2)  # split on first 2 spaces
    return dt,level,msg
```